# subset rows with (1) ALL and (2) ANY columns larger than a specific value

Tags: r, subset, r-faq

I have a data frame with an id column and some (potentially many) columns with values, here 'v1', 'v2':

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), v1 = c(0,15,9,12,7), v2 = c(9,32,6,17,11))
#   id v1 v2
# 1  1  0  9
# 2  2 15 32
# 3  3  9  6
# 4  4 12 17
# 5  5  7 11
```

1. How can I extract rows where ALL values are larger than a certain value, say 10, which should return:

   ```
   #   id v1 v2
   # 2  2 15 32
   # 4  4 12 17
   ```
2. How can I extract rows with ANY (at least one) value is larger than 10:

   ```
   #   id v1 v2
   # 2  2 15 32
   # 4  4 12 17
   # 5  5  7 11
   ```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See functions `all()` and `any()` for the first and second parts of your questions respectively. The `apply()` function can be used to run functions over rows or columns. (`MARGIN = 1` is rows, `MARGIN = 2` is columns, etc). Note I use `apply()` on `df[, -1]` to ignore the `id` variable when doing the comparisons.

Part 1:

```
> df <- data.frame(id=c(1:5), v1=c(0,15,9,12,7), v2=c(9,32,6,17,11))
> df[apply(df[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x > 10)), ]
  id v1 v2
2  2 15 32
4  4 12 17
```

Part 2:

```
> df[apply(df[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) any(x > 10)), ]
  id v1 v2
2  2 15 32
4  4 12 17
5  5  7 11
```

To see what is going on, `x > 10` returns a logical vector for each row (via `apply()` indicating whether each element is greater than 10. `all()` returns `TRUE` if *all* element of the input vector are `TRUE` and `FALSE` otherwise. `any()` returns `TRUE` if *any* of the elements in the input is `TRUE` and `FALSE` if all are `FALSE`.

I then use the logical vector resulting from the `apply()` call

```
> apply(df[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x > 10))
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> apply(df[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) any(x > 10))
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

to subset `df` (as shown above).

Answer (score 8):

This can be done using `apply` with margin 1, which will apply a function to each row. The function to check a given row would be

```
function(row) {all(row > 10)}
```

So the way to extract the rows themselves is

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(row) {all(row > 10)}),]
```

Comment: wait, you want to do `all(row[-1] > 10)` not to account for the `id` column. Or apply the function on `df[-1]`.

Answer (score 4):

One option is looping row-by-row (e.g. with `apply`) and using `any` or `all`, as proposed in the other two answers. However, this can be inefficient for large data frames.

A vectorized approach would be to use `rowSums` to determine the number of values in each row matching your criterion, and filter based on that.

(1) When filtering to rows where ALL values are at least 10, this is the same as filtering to cases where the number of values in a row less than or equal to 10 is 0:

```
df[rowSums(df[,-1] <= 10) == 0,]
#   id v1 v2
# 2  2 15 32
# 4  4 12 17
```

(2) Similarly, `rowSums` can easily be used to compute the rows with ANY (at least one) value is larger than 10:

```
df[rowSums(df[,-1] > 10) > 0,]
#   id v1 v2
# 2  2 15 32
# 4  4 12 17
# 5  5  7 11
```

The speedup is clear with a larger input:

```
set.seed(144)
df <- matrix(sample(c(1, 10, 20), 3e6, replace=TRUE), ncol=3)
system.time(df[apply(df[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x > 10)), ])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.754   0.156   2.102 
system.time(df[rowSums(df[,-1] <= 10) == 0,])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.04    0.01    0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` equivalent is as follows

```
library(dplyr)

#ANY
df %>% rowwise() %>%
  filter(any(across(starts_with("v"), ~ sum((. > 10)))))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
     id    v1    v2
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2    15    32
2     4    12    17
3     5     7    11


#ALL
df %>% rowwise() %>%
  filter(all(across(starts_with("v"), ~ sum((. > 10)))))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Rowwise: 
     id    v1    v2
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2    15    32
2     4    12    17
```